# How to fix Out-String encoding issues in powershell?

Tags: powershell, utf-8, utf-16

I have the following command:

```bsh
& wsl --exec bash -c "echo Hello" | Out-String
```

which returns in the Powershell console an utterly strange formatted string:

```
P l e a s e   e n a b l e   t h e   V i r t u a l   M a c h i n e   P l a t f o r m   W i n d o w s   f e a t u r e   a n d   e n s u r e   v i r t u a l i z a t i o n   
i s   e n a b l e d   i n   t h e   B I O S .


 F o r   i n f o r m a t i o n   p l e a s e   v i s i t   h t t p s : / / a k a . m s / w s l 2 - i n s t a l l
```

How can I fix these encoding issues? When I write it to a file with `& wsl --exec bash -c "exit 0" | Out-String > Log` it contains carbage unicode (the whitspace above) and I dont know which encoding it is:

Comment: The internal encoding for .Net (and thus Powershell) is UTF 16. So 'a' is actually `0x0061`, and the zeroes become e x t r a spaces.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/110

Answer (score 0):

Use `Out-File -FilePath \YOUR_OUTPUT_PATH\ -Encoding utf8` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default environment value:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
```